# What role does a web sever play in hosting of single page applications

Tags: single-page-application

As per my understanding, when user visits a url of a SPA application, the whole application is downloaded including any static html,assets and javascript. Can someone please clarify what role does the host web server play from there on? If after download of all the assets, I turn off the web server the application does not work. But ideally, it should work because now all the code to create any views is with the client already in form of javascript files. Let's assume there are no API calls for data.

Comment: If there are no api-calls then the webserver isn't needed after the initial load.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Question is that why does a SPA need the web server to be running even after the client has downloaded all the assets?

Answer (score 0):

**Yeah it will work**

If the application is fully loaded in browser it will work even **after you turned off or** **disconnect the web server**

- Web Server No Need after the client has downloaded all the assets